# Getting NFC Unique ID within the oncreate method

Tags: android, nfc, uniqueidentifier, oncreate

I am trying to get the unique ID of a NFC tag within the on create method. I have done this successfully using an override method called "onNewIntent" however i want to get it within the oncreate method. Here is what i have tried, the application on my phone crashes when starting up. Please can anyone help. Thanks.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TextView uid;

    private final String[][] techList = new String[][] {
        new String[] {
            NfcA.class.getName(),
            NfcB.class.getName(),
            NfcF.class.getName(),
            NfcV.class.getName(),
            NdefFormatable.class.getName(),
            TagTechnology.class.getName(),
            IsoDep.class.getName(),
            MifareClassic.class.getName(),
            MifareUltralight.class.getName(), 
            Ndef.class.getName()
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        uid = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.UID);
        Intent i = new Intent();
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0);
        filter.addAction(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED);
        NfcAdapter nfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
        nfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, pendingIntent, new IntentFilter[]{filter}, this.techList);
        if (i.getAction().equals(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED)) {
            ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.UID)).setText(ByteArrayToHexString(i.getByteArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_ID)));
        }
    }

    private String ByteArrayToHexString(byte [] inarray) { //converts byte arrays to string
        int i, j, in;
        String [] hex = {"0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","A","B","C","D","E","F"};
        String out= "";

        for(j = 0 ; j < inarray.length ; ++j) 
            {
            in = (int) inarray[j] & 0xff;
            i = (in >> 4) & 0x0f;
            out += hex[i];
            i = in & 0x0f;
            out += hex[i];
            }
        return out;
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the logcat output.

Comment: Ok so basically i create a new intent. I get the default NFC hardware from the device. If a tag is discovered, it should change the textview to the ID of the NFC tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Ok so basically i create a new intent. I get the default NFC hardware from the device. If a tag is discovered, it should change the textview to the ID of the NFC tag

To achieve that, all you have to do is to set the new text and call [`invalidate()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#invalidate%28%29) in `onNewIntent()` so that that `TextView` would be re-drawn with the new text:

```
package com.example.changetext;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.nfc.NfcAdapter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private TextView mNfcAdapterUid;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mNfcAdapterUid = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.nfc_adapter_uid);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            mNfcAdapterUid.setText(ByteArrayToHexString(intent.getByteArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_ID)));
            mNfcAdapterUid.invalidate();
        }
    }

    private String ByteArrayToHexString(byte[] inarray) { // converts byte arrays to string
        int i, j, in;
        String[] hex = {
                "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"
        };
        String out = "";

        for (j = 0; j < inarray.length; ++j) {
            in = inarray[j] & 0xff;
            i = (in >> 4) & 0x0f;
            out += hex[i];
            i = in & 0x0f;
            out += hex[i];
        }
        return out;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help, i have already done the code using onNewIntent, however i needed to get the UID in the onCreate method.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be mixing two concepts here: NFC intents registered in the app manifest and foreground dispatch.

**Automatically starting an app based on NFC events:**

This mechanism requires you to register intent filters in your app manifest, e.g.

```
<activity ...>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"/>
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"
               android:resource="@xml/nfc_tech_filter" />
</activity>
```

Then your activity will be automatically started upon tag detection. (NOTE: Avoid using the `TAG_DISCOVERED` intent for this type of dispatch as that intent (when used in the manifest) is meant as a fall-back only!)

Now, if your app is started, you can detect if it was started by the `TECH_DISCOVERED` intent in your `onCreate()` method:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    uid = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.UID);

    Intent i = getIntent();  // get the intent that started us
    if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED.equals(i.getAction())) {
        uid.setText(ByteArrayToHexString(i.getByteArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_ID)));
    }
}
```

---

**Foreground dispatch system:**

The foreground dispatch system is used to register your *current foreground activity* to be notified about (and to get highest priority for receiving) NFC events. You use it by registering for the relevant intent (`TAG_DISCOVERED` is fine in that case) with the `enableForegroundDispatch()` method. Upon receiving an NFC event, your activity is notified through `onNewIntent()`.

Keep in mind, however, that you are only allowed to register for the foreground dispatch while your activity is the foreground activity (i.e. you must register in `onResume()` and must deregister in `onPause()`), otherwise your app will block NFC events or crash (depending on the Android version). So **never** use `enableForegroundDispatch()` in `onCreate()`.